# visual studio code keeps creating my css file to be in the same folder as my scss file

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, compiler-errors, node-sass

Whenever I try placing my css file in a different folder to my sass file, the minute I select the scss watch complier, a new css file gets re-created in the same folder where my scss is placed.

I am trying to keep them separate, is this even an option?

The screenshot shows the different css folders I created trying to keep them seperate, but the watch compiler seems to over-ride this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Live Sass Compiler to change the `savePath` for the compiled files.

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
   {
      "savePath": [Any path you want]
   }
]
```

[Here is the full documentation](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md) of the extension and [how you can edit VSCode settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).